# Tempdata not working in ASP.Net MVC 5 when setting httpCookies in web config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I set httpCookies in my web.cofig, TempData stops working in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

For my testing, I created an empty ASP.NET MVC 5 project and verified the same. Can you please tell me what are the other ways to use a TempData in this case.

I tried to google but did not get any luck.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "test";

        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {

        //Here TempData is empty
        //I can use parameters in About, but I dont want message in my url
        var test = TempData["Message"];

        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Have you changed `<httpCookies requireSSL="false" />` to `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />`? `requireSSL` parameter will affect the session handling when using HTTPS protocol, thus emptying `TempData` content.

Comment: As per customer requirement, we need requireSSL to be true. So even though it works with requireSSL as false, I cannot do that.

Comment: Using `TempData.Keep(“Message”)` may work, but seems that your problem initiated from session state management. `TempData` content(s) available only till the target view was fully loaded, it should be used only between current and subsequent request.

Comment: Where can i put the "TempData.Keep(Message)" call.

Comment: `Keep` method should be placed in first action method, due to `TempData`'s behavior. It retains `TempData` content based from defined key when passing to second action method (also see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/tempdata-vs-session-in-mvc1 for `TempData` and `Session` comparison).

Comment: Apologise for the late reply as I had some bigger issues on hand on this project. There is no point in calling the 'keep' method in the first action, because we are just assigning it here itself. Anyways, I tried the same but wont work either,

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "test";
         TempData.Keep("Message");
        return RedirectToAction("About");
    }  does not work